# Connect with Wi-Fi WPS PBC on rooted Android 12

Tags: wi-fi

Please note that I am totally aware that WPS is not secure, however, I still want to use it.

My phone is a rooted Samsung S20FE running Android 12.

I am looking for a way to connect to a Wi-Fi network accepting WPS PBC (push button) connections, since Google decided to remove this feature from Android. There are dozens of apps on the Play store which implement WPS PIN connections:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wps%20wifi&c=apps&gl=us

All these apps propose usual pins, custom ones, null one, brut force, but I spent a lot of time reading descriptions and trying them, none propose the PBC feature !

I also checked on F-Droid, "WPS" request does not return anything.

Is there an app that allows to do that? Even if I have to download source code myself and run it from a terminal application?

Why all these apps are not implementing PBC? Is it prevented by the OS, even with a rooted phone, or are all these apps banned from the store?

Comment: As your phone is rooted you have access to the lower parts of the OS and Wifi system which are very close to Linux, so have you checked the various questions and answers on stackexchange regarding WPS PBC and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Well, answering to myself:

I could find a python script running with Termux running a PBC session:
https://github.com/drygdryg/OneShot#termux

I could install it with the installer script, I also had to install `openssl` with: `pkg install openssl`.

I finally used Termux:Widget and API to run a wrap script from the main screen and copy the PSK to the clipboard:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~

while true; do

    echo
    echo Launching OneShot in PBC mode

    sudo python3 ~/OneShot/oneshot.py -i wlan0 --pbc | tee wps.tmp

    if grep 'WPA PSK' wps.tmp ; then

        ssid=$( grep 'AP SSID:' wps.tmp | tail -1 )
        psk=$( grep 'WPA PSK:' wps.tmp | tail -1 )

        psk=${psk:14:-1}
        ssid=${ssid:14:-1}

        while true ; do
            sel=$(termux-dialog sheet -v "Copy SSID: $ssid,Copy PWD: $psk,Retry,Exit" | awk '/index/ {print $2}')

            case $sel in
            0)  termux-clipboard-set $ssid
                ;;

            1)  termux-clipboard-set $psk
                ;;

            2)  rm -f wps.tmp
                break
                ;;

            3)  rm -f wps.tmp
                am startservice -a com.termux.service_stop com.termux/.app.TermuxService
                #exit
                ;;
            esac

        done
    else
        echo
        echo "NOT FOUND, retrying..."
        sleep 3
    fi

done
```